# How to get values of the repeating attribute from input xml in to single value by using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, repeat

The problem I'm facing seems simple, but being a novice in everything XSL - I'm yet to find a proper solution. What I want to do is build a string by concatenating the results , that I can later on use as a value for an attribute in excel.Im tring to save the values of the repeating attribute into single value (seperated by commas) using xslt.

Input file:

```
<root>
<contentattributes>
    <attribute name="a_archive" value="false"/>
    <attribute name="qa_impacted_fct_areas" value="CA IS: Information Solutions"/>
    <attribute name="qa_impacted_fct_areas" value="CA_Materials_Management"/>
    <attribute name="qa_impacted_fct_areas" value="CA QO IO S&amp;SM: Validation Compliance"/>
</contentattributes>
<contentattributes>
    <attribute name="a_archive" value="false"/>
      <attribute name=" qa_impacted_fct_areas " value="CA_Materials_Management"/>
    <attribute name=" qa_impacted_fct_areas " value="CA QO IO S&amp;SM: Validation Compliance"/>
</contentattributes>
<contentattributes>
    <attribute name="a_archive" value="false"/>
        <attribute name=" qa_impacted_fct_areas " value="CA_Materials_Management"/>
</contentattributes>
</root>
```

Desired Ouput File:

```
<root>
<contentattributes>

<!--Other Values-->
<Data ss:Type="String"> CA IS: Information Solutions, CA_Materials_Management, CA QO IO S&amp;SM: Validation Compliance </Data>
</contentattributes>

<contentattributes>
<!--Other Values-->
<Data ss:Type="String"> CA IS: Information Solutions, CA QO IO S&amp;SM: Validation Compliance </Data>
</contentattributes>

<contentattributes>

<!--Other Values-->
<Data ss:Type="String"> CA IS: Information Solutions</Data>
</contentattributes>
</root>
```

Please help me how to make XSLT for this required output XML.I also tried

```
<xsl:variable name="qa_impacted_fct_areas" >
  <xsl:value-of select="/root/contentattributes/attribute[@name='qa_impacted_fct_areas']/@value" separator=";" />
</xsl:variable>
```

But Cant able to Get my output

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xsl:for-each-group**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="contentattributes">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="attribute" group-by="@name[normalize-space(.)='qa_impacted_fct_areas']">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@value" separator=", "/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </Data>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think making complecate with `for-each-group` here we have only need to keep values through `xsl:value-of` as well in `2.0`:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="contentattributes">
                    <contentattributes>
                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                            <xsl:value-of select="attribute[normalize-space(@name)='qa_impacted_fct_areas']/@value" separator=", "/>
                        </Data>
                    </contentattributes>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
```